# Settting up line separator in Maven

Tags: java, maven

We are working on a multi module Maven project where in one sub project we have some resources file (free marker template files). When we create EAR out of the project depending on Operating System Maven is updating line separator in template files.
If we run mvn install on windows it keeps line separator as  and when we run it on linux it changes line separator to .
Template are created on Windows machine and have default separator as , we don't want Maven to changes to  even if we build project on windows / linux. As code is always deployed on Windows machine and fails when encounters linux line separator.
Is there any way to tell Maven not to mess up with line separators?
Project POM looks like

```
<project>
   <parent>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>Foo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>FooBatch</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <spring-version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.21</version>
        </dependency>
        // and more dependencies
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

and here is the Parent POM

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>Foo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>FooBatch</module>
        <module>FooEJB</module>
        <module>FooEAR</module>
    </modules>

    <build>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/ -->
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- skips surefire tests without skipping failsafe tests. Property 
                    value seems to magically default to false -->
                <skipTests>${skipUnitTests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                        <argLine>${jacoco.agent.arg}</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!-- skips failsafe tests without skipping surefire tests. Property 
                    value seems to magically default to false -->
                <skipITs>${skipITTests}</skipITs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-site</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you filtering the resources? Could you post your POM?

Comment: @Tunaki nop, I have added POM to the post.

Comment: Could you post the parent's POM then? Maven shouldn't mess up with your file separators if there is no filtering or, more generally, if the files aren't being just copied but processed by a plugin somehow.

Comment: @Tunaki have added parent pom too.

Comment: I still think this is missing some information. This shouldn't happen. Are any plugins processing those files?

Comment: @Tunaki I have added complete parent POM, we don't have any plugin in sub module POM. We don't have any plugin other than standard ones like resource / compiler plugin which touches resource files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to your parent pom.

```
<project>
...
  <properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
```